# whether java creates forms and its controls only through code?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a hardware engineer, having a very good knowledge about C.

Recently I worked with C#, made some desktop applications but for some reasons I don't find C# suited for my needs.

After some general reading, google searching and tutorial reading, I think that Java is exactly what I am looking for in visual programming. Furthermore I'm suprised how close it is with C#, so learning time will decrease drastically.

As I understand, eclipse is the common enviroment for Java.

**My question is this:**

- Every Java tutorial I've seen the past few hours, creates a form and its controls only through code.
- In C# there is the toolbox (you know texboxes, buttons etc) and a properties window for each control.

Is this available also in Eclipse? Or it is just code?

Comment: Well thank you all for your participation in this thread. My conclusions were clear and now I've got what I need in my hands to make my decisions.

Comment: I am using Adobe Dream weaver software for this purpose. But its a paid one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently discovered two plugins for Eclipse called [WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/index.html) and [WindowTester](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wintester/html/index.html). These tools were made by a company that was purchased by Google, who then made these tools freely available. WindowBuilder allows you to build Swing, SWT, and GWT user interfaces, and WindowTester allows you to test the user interfaces that you constructed.

I haven't had the opportunity to dive very deep into these tools, but they seem to be solid.

Comment: yup, +1, I forgot about the windowbuilder story.

Comment: I should play around with them tonight, but I haven't been touching very many UIs, doing mostly work with legacy systems or libraries.

Answer (score 5):

There is a good one in [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/). There are a couple of plugins in Eclipse (like [this](http://eclipse.dzone.com/announcements/visual-swing-designer-eclipse)), but I can't vouch for their quality (I've never worked with them). Since I'm an Eclipse user, and NetBeans was rather buggy at that time, when we were making a GUI project, we used to draw our forms in NetBeans and then write the rest in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me a few words about NetBeans and its toolbox?

Comment: the GUI tool is pretty good. And I guess they've improved it since the last time I used it

Comment: Imo the only really useful GUI tool for eclipse is [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) - a google project with some quite interesting properties (editing or adding to generated code!). Every other GUI builder was just horrible to use when compared to the one included in VS. Also allows to use all usual Java GUI frameworks (not sure about awt though? but who'd voluntarily use that one)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. Everything you think could be available is available with Eclipse as [plugins](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/)

Comment: Thank you too for your answer. This is good news, plug-ins or not they will do the job!

Comment: well, the answer is pretty generic. There can be plugins, but there might not be one that you need. @Bragboy you could at least link a few eclipse gui plugins

Comment: @Bozho : You are right, I should have least provided a link. I have edited the post now.

Answer (score 1):

You have two Options that I know of. Netbeans and Intellij. I am sure MyEclipse comes with Swing Designer, but I have not used it.

If you are using it for a simple project, then Netbeans should be adequate. But I believe it is slightly intrusive as an IDE. Intellij is much better, but its not free.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok I just googled both, they seem quite good. What is the difference between Eclipse and my Eclipse?

Comment: MyEclipse is a Commerical IDE developer on top of Eclipse. You can consider it as a heavily modded version of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working JSP and JSF in Eclipse, you can use the Java EE version of Eclipse (I use Helios edition but havent used Indigo yet). the built-in web page and Swing editors are a bit crude but usable. You can also download and install the Google Web Toolkit to Eclipse which I think includes a WYSIWYG-type interface. Android SDK is available for developing Android mobile apps and comes with its own  WYSIWYG-type interface.

NetBeans is good and you can try JDeveloper from Oracle (especially if you plan to work with Oracle application servers).  IntelliJ and MyEclipse cost money but are options for you as noted. (Rational from IBM also but is very resource heavy and costly)